# CleverTap notification settings in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, clevertap

I am using firebase in my iOS project for notifications. Instead of the APNS certificates, I am using auth keys (that can be downloaded only once). Now the problem is, the auth key file that has been uploaded on Firebase is lost as it was uploaded by some other developer an year ago. Now I need that auth key file to upload on CleverTap for notifications to work but as the file is lost, I am not able to do so.

Now I can't upload a new key on firebase as the existing users might not receive notifications. What option do I have to make it work so that the existing users continue receiving the notifications and I can make CleverTap notifications work?

Answer (score 0):

Clevertap push notifications config works with both Auth keys & push certificate.
If you don't have auth key, you can upload the valid push certificate to make it work.

Once the above process is done, if you initiate any push notification all your users will receive that.  It does not matter whether they are new or existing users.